# tkinter: Wait a second in Canvas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So, I got code so far that will make a yellow circle appear in a blue circle, but the problem is that I want the yellow circle to upload to the canvas a second after the blue circle appears.

This is what I've got so far:

```
import tkinter
import time

root = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

for i in range(100):
    canvas.create_line(20 * i, 0, 20 * i, 800)
    canvas.create_line(0, 20 * i, 800, 20 * i)

canvas.create_oval(20, 20, 480, 480, fill="blue")
canvas.create_oval(100, 100, 400, 400, fill="yellow")


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.after()`

```
import tkinter
import time

root = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

for i in range(100):
    canvas.create_line(20 * i, 0, 20 * i, 800)
    canvas.create_line(0, 20 * i, 800, 20 * i)

canvas.create_oval(20, 20, 480, 480, fill="blue")
make_oval= lambda : canvas.create_oval(100, 100, 400, 400, fill="yellow")
root.after(1000,make_oval)


root.mainloop()
```